# What is the Best way to schedule tasks and monitor them in java

Tags: java, multithreading, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler, polling

I need help from you guys.

I am trying to design a data polling system in which I want to poll data from hundreds or even thousands of devices ( Modbus device using Modbus Tcp/ip protocol). I have implemented a small program which is able to read and write to one device.

Now i wanted to design a robust system which will read data from every device as per scheduled interval. Each device will have different interval and this interval will be stored in database. 
I have googled a lot for this and I got to know options like
1. Timetasks and timer to schedule tasks
2. Quartz schedulers
3. Linux cron jobs

I can use any of these but my concern is to monitoring the tasks. I can not afford to loose the data. Every second data is getting generated on devices and it should get read by scheduled tasks on server. If tasks fails or scheduler fails then how I can reschedule them. Which is the best way to monitor the tasks and make sure every second data is getting read.

Comment: If you decide to use Quartz which sounds like a good choice for your use-case, and you are concerned about monitoring and restarting your tasks in case they fail, I recommend that you look into QuartzDesk [I am biased here]. In QD you can set up notification rules that can notify you of any condition that occurs during the execution of your jobs. If you want to auto-restart failed jobs, then you can use QD job chains. Failed jobs can be restarted immediatelly, after a fixed or dynamically computed delay. No code changes. If you need to some pointers, real-life examples etc. just let me know.

Comment: If you have so many devices, schedule a task to monitor them doesn't really seem a good idea. A more modern approach would be to use event sourcing (e.g. For any relevant action, your devices add an event to a queue that is read by an aggregator written  in whatever language you want.